# How can I run docker behind the GRE Tunnel?

Tags: docker, networking

So I am having a pterodactyl installation on my node,
I am aware that pterodactyl runs using docker so to protect my Backend IP from being exposed when connecting to the servers I am using a GRE Tunnel from X4B.net
After installing the script I was provided by X4B I got this message

> Also Note: This script does not adjust the configuration of your applications. You should ensure your applications are bound to 0.0.0.0 or the appropriate tunnel IP.

At first I was confused and tried connecting to my server but nothing worked, so I was thinking that it was due the docker not being bounded to 0.0.0.0

As for the network layout I was provided with:

> 10.16.1.200/30    Network,
> 10.16.1.201 Unified Gateway,
> 10.16.1.202 Bound via NAT to 103.249.70.63,
> 10.16.1.203 Broadcast

So If I host a minecraft server what IP address would I use?

Comment: My guess would be 10.16.1.202. If the server and the docker container are in the same namespace, 0.0.0.0 should also do the work. Make sure this pterodactyl thing either uses the host network or your server is at least in pterodactyl's network.